# How do I detect when a PC has been completely shut down?

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell, cmd.exe, shutdown

I am able to

1. shut down a remote computer via `shutdown /s /m \\\MachineName`; and
2. cut that remote computer's power supply (think power switch with IP featuring TelNet communication).

I want to execute both tasks sequentially, but for obvious reasons Task 2 should not be invoked before Task 1 has succeeded completely.

Both tasks are executed within an application (VB6). They run as intended, individually. But serially, I need to reliably find out when the remote machine has been shut down completely, before doing Task 2.

So the question is: how can I reliably detect termination of Task 1? Is it even possible? For example, could I use a shell script?

Timing Task 1 is not an option: it can run for an unpredictable duration (think Windows updates, "don't switch off this machine until finished").

Comment: You cannot. At some point, windows disables the network and from that moment you simply can't know from the pc itself if its still on or not. If your power switch can measure how much voltage is being drawn (A UPS can) then you can measure the voltage and once it reaches 0, you will know the pc is powered off.

Comment: It probably won't reach zero but there should be a significant drop.

Comment: @LPChip: interesting idea, but that would assume an UPS for each individual computer. Albeit there are 3 such devices here, they do cover plenty of electrical stuff (multi-room-based). And there are more than 3 computers here. Shouldn't I be able to at least Ping a computer during its Windows update? After all, the update comes from the Internet.

Comment: No, the update is downloaded when you are still in windows. Windows then shuts down and exits the kernel. Outside of windows, the updates are installed. This is required so the update can alter files that are otherwise in use. I used UPS as example. There are powerbricks that can be network controlled too. There must be one that can read the wattage of all devices.

Comment: You may be able to detect the presence of power on an external interface, eg certain motherboards have BIOS settings of which interfaces maintain power when the computer is off. If there is an HDMI interface, this will normally lose any power from its control lines.

Comment: You really need to either measure power draw or monitor a suitable indicator like the Power LED output.

Comment: If this is important, get a computer with a [baseboard management controller](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/baseboard-management-controller), then user SNMP to monitor the system's Power On state. BMC controllers operate "out-of-band" and can report on the system's state without a running OS or even the machine being powered on.

Comment: @Twisty, what a cool feature! Unfortunately, all computers were just replaced, recently, and of course, they do not feature BMC (at least as per the missing BIOS menu). I'm trying to find out, though, if IPMI exists on the board and whether BMC can be added or not (doubt it, though, due to expecting a 2nd NIC, which seems not to be present). Are you possibly aware, if there are stand-alone IPMI adapters, connecting somehow (USB?) to the boards?

Comment: @Herb I'm not sure this functionally can be added to a system that doesn't already support it. [Another possibility](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/56538/how-to-remotely-control-your-pc-even-when-it-crashes/amp/) is something like Intel vPro...though I'm not sure if it works the way you need it to.

Comment: @Twisty, it might, thanks for yet another possibility, but well, there is no vPro on these i7's, and then - "The free viewer will work for most remote purposes but you will lose some functionality like [...] the ability to power the machine on and off. If you want to take advantage of more features you are going to need to pay for the RealVNC Viewer Plus ($99)."

Comment: You could always do what a UPS does and start a countdown timer when the OS shutdown begins and cut the power when the timer expires. I've managed servers configured this way for years and it works reliably.

Comment: @Twisty: doesn't this assume, that a possible Windows Update does not take more than x minutes? I have not seen a Windows update last longer than 10 minutes certainly does not imply that it never won't.

Comment: @DanielB: I am willing to spend a bit of money (but not a fortune relative to the computer price) for dedicated power monitoring devices (ideally inserted between power outlets and monitored PCs, drawing own power, and featuring a NIC so that the actual power consumption can be obtained), but my googling efforts were of not much use. Are you aware of an appropriate search term?

Comment: @Herb In a best-practice environment, updates are installed on a schedule and associated reboots preformed immediately afterward. We don't want machines with an unknown possibility updates need to be installed during an unrelated shutdown, lest our timer expire before the machine is ready for the power to be cut. If you solve this problem, the timer method will work nicely.

Comment: @LPChip, if you turn your comment into an answer, I'd accept it as the solution.

Comment: @Herb here you are. :)

Comment: @Herb Just use a Raspberry Pi or whatever with an appropriate circuit wired to the power LED output. Or any PSU output except +5Vsb, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.

At some point, windows disables the network and from that moment you simply can't know from the pc itself if its still on or not. If your power switch can measure how much voltage is being drawn (A UPS can) then you can measure the voltage and once it reaches 0, you will know the pc is powered off.

To clarify how windows updates work; the update is downloaded when you are still in windows. Windows then shuts down and exits the kernel. Outside of windows, the updates are installed. This is required so the update can alter files that are otherwise in use. I used UPS as example. There are powerbricks that can be network controlled too. There must be one that can read the wattage of all devices.